# In SAS linear regression, how to perform dummy codding for a 4 level categorical predictor variable?

Tags: sas

I have a response variable like Clinical indicator and will perform a multiple regression based on a series predictor variables, all of the predictor variables are numeric or categorical dummy variable, only except for race being the 4-level categorical variable. To perform this regression, I need dummy coding for the race variable. What's the exact coding or option for statement?

Answer (score 0):

Many regression PROCs like `proc glmselect` do not require dummy coding. You can specify your categorical variables directly with the `class` statement.

```
proc glmselect data=sashelp.cars;
    class make origin;
    model horsepower = make origin msrp / showpvalues selection=stepwise(sle=0.1 sls=0.05);
run;
```

[Following Rick Wicklin's dummy coding method](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2020/08/31/best-generate-dummy-variables-sas.html), you can use `proc glmselect` to generate dummies for you. You can turn this into a macro variable to make generating dummies fast and simple.

```
%macro get_dummies(data=, vars=, out=dummies, drop=NO);
    
    data _tmp_;
        set &data.;
        __y__ = 0;
    run;

    proc glmselect 
        data=_tmp_ 
        noprint 
        outdesign(addinputvars) = &out.(drop=__y__ 
                                             %if(%upcase(&drop.)=YES) %then %do;
                                                &vars.
                                             %end;
                                       )
        ;

        class &vars.;
        model __y__ = &vars. / noint selection=none;
    run;

    proc datasets lib=work nolist;
        delete _tmp_;
    quit;
%mend;
```

Example:

```
%get_dummies(data=sashelp.cars, vars=make origin, drop=yes);
```

If `drop=yes`, then it drops the original variables and only leaves the dummy-encoded values.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. But I still want to know about dummy coding or maybe some options in just linear regression. Could you provide detailed solution?

Comment: I updated the answer with a macro to perform dummy coding.

Comment: Thank you very much for this macro coding. It's been very helpful.